# Design Database Poller Oracle Thread

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

1) I have a Oracle database table "publishmessage", which has n number of entries.

2) Table "publishmessage" has column "status", which says its processed(P) or unprocessed(U).

3) I should write a JAVA poller, which will look for the unprocessed(U) entries and process.

4) Once processed, column "status" should be changed to "P".

```
For ex:
Before Processing:

publishmessage
messageid status
1           U
2           U


After Processing:

publishmessage
messageid status
1           P
2           P
3           U <-- new entry inserted to table "publishmessage", which will be picked in the next polling.
```

How can I design or prgram in JAVA.

Comment: You are using the tags spring and hibernate, which seem to indicate that you want to use an ORM.  I'd really suggest you practice a bit with databases and Java using plain JDBC, [the Oracle JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you take a look at 2 things

1. Spring Data JDBC Extensions | [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)
2. Spring Integration | [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html)

The first has support for [Oracle Advanced Queuing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qintro.htm) which basically lets you use the database as a message queue and lets you access it from java with plain JMS.

The second has out-of-the-box support for JDBC driven inbound gateways, it lets you specify the select and update queries and you don't have to write your own polling mechanism, merely configure it.

Before trying to roll your own solution I would investigate both of these solutions.